# How to change permissions on luks-dmcrypt encrypted device?

Tags: permissions, luks, dmcrypt

I encrypted a device using these directions

```
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdb1
sudo cryptsetup -y -v luksFormat /dev/sdb1
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 $name #change "$name" to any name you wish
#now format
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/$name
sudo mkdir /media/mount_point
sudo mount /dev/mapper/$name /media/mount_point
```

When I unlock and mount the setup, I can't write or copy anything to it because root is the owner and all permissions are only for root. Can I change this so that I have access to it?

Answer (score 5):

Just to clarify for others as I've stumbled on this question when first searching for it on Google:

**Issue**: After doing all the necessary setup for a LUKS container file/harddisk that is already mounted with root, a user account has not write privileges to it, only read. (this is the case for most tutorials and instructions above)

**Solution**:

We need to change the permissions of the newly-minted filesystem that is in the encrypted harddisk/file container.

Using the example in the example where `/dev/mapper/$name` has already been mounted to  `/media/mount_point` with a command like:

`sudo mount /dev/mapper/$name /media/mount_point`

Open a terminal in your account and type **enter this command**:

> **`sudo chown -R yourUserName /media/mount_point`**

For example if joe has a mount point named myEncryptedHD he should do:

`sudo chown -R joe /media/myEncryptedHD`

What this does is Joe changes the owner of all files in `myEncrypted` to `joe`, and he now has read and write access. Life is good.

If you decide you don't want R/W permissions anymore, just `sudo chown -R root /media/mount_point` and you'll revoke your rights.

References for [chown examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/chown-examples/) for more complicated permissions handling and a [related question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/311689/how-to-write-as-a-normal-user-to-a-mounted-dm-crypt-luks-partition) with a comment on the answer that also suggests the alternative `sudo chmod -R 775 /media/mount_point` that will set read write execute permissions on user, group and only read and execute (5) for others. [A chmod man page for further info](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)

Comment: your mount method didn't work for me, because after rebooting and plugging in, my device was already mounted as /dev/mapper/luks-series-of-hash-codes 

Your tutorial only worked, after I did repeat following "mount or remount encrypted partition" steps described in the tutorial, I used to encrypt my device: https://archive.ph/02NKD#selection-2057.0-2057.46  And instead of chown myUserName I used chmod 777 so I can write on my portable device from any Linux PC which knows LUKS: https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-777/

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can change this. After you get Root Privileges

```
sudo su
```

you should use

```
chmod 777 /directory/of/the/device
```

I am not sure if the device should be mounted or not before you attempt this.